# VB.NET : Custom Control not saving data from a subclass.

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-controls

I have a custom control, it works fine for general data, I.E.

```
    Public Class CircularProgressBar : Inherits Control
        Private _barSeperation As Long = 1
        Public Property Seperation() As Long
            Get
                Return _barSeperation
            End Get
            Set(ByVal v As Long)
                If v < 0 Then v = 0
                _barSeperation = v : Invalidate()
                Call SetMinimumSize()
            End Set
        End Property

...etc
```

And displays in the properties window (when editing the form) just fine.

Take this however:

```
Private _barsData As BarsHolder
Public Property Bars() As BarsHolder
    Get
        Return _barsData
    End Get
    Set(ByVal v As BarsHolder)
        _barsData = v : Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property
```

Where BarsHolder could be something like:

```
<TypeConverter(GetType(ExpandableObjectConverter))>
    Public Class BarsHolder
        Private _value As Long = 0
        Public Property Value() As Long
            Get
                Return _value
            End Get
            Set(ByVal v As Long)
                _value = v : _parent.Invalidate()
            End Set
        End Property
..etc
```

It works fine and displays in the properties window when editing, but when I reopen the form or run the project, the data resets.

I can exactly tell what it is, the designer code does not add any subclass coding, so when I reopen the project or run the program it defaults to the default values. How can I have subclass coding save it's data in the designer when I edit the values?

Thanks!

Comment: Add the `<Serializable>` attribute to the BarsHolder class so the object can be stored in the form's .resx file.  If the class is simple and can be encoded into a string then you could write a TypeConverter for the class.

Comment: Nits: It is not a user control if it inherits from Control, and it is not a subclass - just a nested Type.  Are the values really so large that you need `long`?  Seems like a lot of wrappers just for a value.

Comment: Sorry, was just an example, But yeah.

Makes sense Hans, thank you for the info.

Alot of the coding was removed, but some things can handle the _value (maximum/minimum in the set area) as well, things like that.